# Combining results from 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 10, with the following structure and data:

```
create table table1(
  id serial primary key
);

create table table2(
  id serial primary key
);

create table table3(
  id serial primary key,
  table1_id int,
  table2_id int
);

insert into table1 (id) values (1), (2), (3);
insert into table2 (id) values (1), (2);
insert into table3 (id, table1_id, table2_id) values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1);
```

I want all combinations of table1 and table2 that don't have an entry in table3, essentially this sort of result:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| table1.id | table2.id | table3.id |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         1 | 1         |
|         2 |         1 | 3         |
|         3 |         1 | null      |
|         1 |         2 | 2         |
|         2 |         2 | null      |
|         3 |         2 | null      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Notice how the results have all the possible combinations from table1 and table2, with the corresponding id from table3.

Eventually, I would like to get the query to only return rows where table3.id is NULL:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| table1.id | table2.id | table3.id |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         3 |         1 | null      |
|         2 |         2 | null      |
|         3 |         2 | null      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am unsure on how to even approach this query: **join** or **inner selects** or maybe even **excludes**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `CROSS JOIN` (cartesian product) on `table1` and `table2` then `table3` `LEFT JOIN` base on the `CROSS JOIN` result set.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
create table table1(
  id serial primary key
);

create table table2(
  id serial primary key
);

create table table3(
  id serial primary key,
  table1_id int,
  table2_id int
);

insert into table1 (id) values (1), (2), (3);
insert into table2 (id) values (1), (2);
insert into table3 (id, table1_id, table2_id) values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.id,t2.id,t3.id 
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 
on t3.table1_id = t1.id and t3.table2_id = t2.id
where t3.id is null;
```

---

**Result**

```
t1id  t2id  t3id
2      2    null
3      1    null
3      2    null
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8hNAN8Q3Vkn99EBvU78Kby/1)

Comment: @joao Yes do descartes products